# Infinspan console shows only one node for clustered servers in the cache node view

Tags: infinispan

We are working with infinspan version 9.4.8 in a domain mode with cluster of two hosts servers with two nodes.
In the statistics of the cluster view we can see that both nodes get hits but when we look at the view of the cache nodes for a distributed cache we can see only one node in the nodes view

[image]

In console of infinspan 8 we used to have the two nodes in the cache nodes view but after upgrading to version 9 it is not the case 
Could you please advise if it is bug in the console for version 9.4.8 or something is missed in the configuration

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug which has just been fixed and will be included in the upcoming 9.4.18.Final release. The issue is tracked by [ISPN-11265](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-11265).

In the future please utilise the [Infinispan JIRA](https://issues.redhat.com/projects/ISPN) directly if you suspect a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your support Ryan but I don't have access to view this issue.

Comment: Sorry about that, the issue should be viewable now.